# Windows service: How to cleanup with a NOP OnStop()

Tags: windows, service, resources, .net-assembly

A windows service program is implemented by deriving from ServiceBase class with C#. The service will load an assembly with a background thread in OnStart() and start from a function entry point through an InvokeMember() call. Inside the assembly dll/background thread, the program will allocate various system resources during its running. Now the problem is that the OnStop() implemented as a NOP, so there is no hook I can use. Without changing the OnStop() implementation, how do I clean up allocated resources when the service is stopped by "sc stop aService"?

I tried various ways but looks like there is no way to intercept "sc stop" message besides changing OnStop(). I tried to add a try/catch/finally block with a backgroud cleanup thread but I can't get the finally clause called. Tried AppDomain UnhandledException and ProcessExit handlers and that did not do anything either. So what're the effects of a SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP(sc stop) on background threads? Is there anyway I can clean up resources within my assembly/dll at all?

Comment: You'll have to implement OnStop().  Throwing an exception is pointless, it will be caught and logged.  Signal the worker thread to exit with an AutoResetEvent.

Comment: I guess my thinking is that after "sc stop", there are many things will happen to the service, in my case, it will terminate several threads, unload assembly/dll, may exit AppDomain and a few other things if I add "hooks" into it. I should be able to add some kind of "exit" handler which will always be called, right?

Comment: Well, don't get carried away.  The Stop command really only means "stop doing what you normally do", it is not a Terminate command.  The admin will only use it occasionally to troubleshoot something.